# The longest common sub sequence algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I was going through the longest common sub sequence problem in the INTRODUCTION TO ALGORITHMS by CLRS.But i was unable to understand the thought process behind it. Most other problems explained were pretty intuitive and am confident that i can solve similar problems in the future but i am unable to visualize the LCS problem as i do not understand the logic behind how the optimal substructure is determined.

the book gives the following explanation for the optimal sub structure

**Theorem 15.1 (Optimal substructure of an LCS)

Let X == and Y == be sequences, and let Z =
 be any LCS of X and Y.
1. If `xm = yn`,then `zk = xm = yn` and `Zk−1` is an LCS of `Xm−1` and `Yn−1`.
2. If `xm != yn` ,then `zk = xm` implies that `Z` is an LCS of `Xm−1` and `Y`.
3. If `xm != yn`,then `zk = yn` implies that `Z` is an LCS of `X` and `Yn−1`.
Proof (1) If `zk != xm`, then we could append `xm = yn` to `Z` to obtain a common
subsequence of `X` and `Y` of length `k + 1`, contradicting the supposition that `Z` is
a longest common subsequence of `X` and `Y`. Thus, we must have `zk = xm = yn`.

Now, the preﬁx `Zk−1` is a `length-(k − 1)` common subsequence of `Xm−1` and `Yn−1`.
We wish to show that it is an LCS. Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that
there is a common subsequence `W` of `Xm−1` and `Yn−1` with length greater than `k−1`.
Then, appending `xm = yn` to `W` produces a common subsequence of `X` and `Y`
whose length is greater than `k`, which is a contradiction.

(2) If `zk != xm`,then `Z` is a common subsequence of `Xm−1` and `Y`. If there were a
common subsequence `W` of `Xm−1` and `Y` with length greater than `k`,then `W` would
also be a common subsequence of `Xm` and `Y`, contradicting the assumption that `Z`
is an LCS of `X` and `Y`.

(3) The proof is symmetric to (2).**

The proof is clear but i can't see how they came up with the optimal substructure.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the recurrence part of the the following link:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#LCS_function_defined

These recurrence relations are nothing but optimal substructure and overlapping sub-problem equalities.